# bus error (core dumped) when installing ember-cli in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ember-cli

I am installing ember cli but I get this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvuBJ.png)

I was wondering what might be the problem considering that I have uninstalled things that have its support like nodejs and reinstalled them again.

Comment: It might be worth [creating an issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues) on the ember-cli repository.

Comment: I guess so, since I have been trying it with no idea to go where next. Thanks for the idea.